# MongoDB: Aggregation Arrays

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, aggregation-framework

I'm having difficulties creating an aggregation for the following contents of a collection:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("574ffe9bda461e4b4b0043ab"),
  "hostname": "baklap4",
  "timestamp": NumberLong(1464860311),
  "networkList": [
    {
      "name": "wlp5s0",
      "receive": NumberLong(53845),
      "transmit": NumberLong(20999)
    },
    {
      "name": "enp6s0",
      "receive": NumberLong(0),
      "transmit": NumberLong(0)
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem here is Networklist is an array which holds the name of the device and how much data have gone in and out.

What i would like to have:
I want an average of `receive` and `transmit` based upon the name which is unique.

Apart from that the average will be taken over all the documents split by 300 seconds (for this i'm using the `timestamp` field).

My Query till now looks like this:

```
db.NetworkInfo.aggregate([ 
    { "$unwind": "$networkList" }, 
    { "$group": 
        { "_id": 
            { "interval": 
                { "$subtract": [ "$timestamp", { "$mod": [ "$timestamp", 60 * 5 ] } ] }
            }, 
         "receive": { "$avg": "$networkList.receive" },
         "transmit": { "$avg": "$networkList.transmit" },  
         "timestamp": { "$max": "$timestamp" } 
       } 
    }, 
    { "$project": 
        { "_id": 0, 
          "receive": 1,
          "transmit": 1, 
          "timestamp": 1 
        } 
    }, 
    {$sort: {"timestamp": -1}}
])
```

This query will go through all of the documents and splits them in groups divided by 300 seconds.
Then it'll calculate an average for receive and transmited data. 
But as there are 2 entries in network list it'll make an average of in this case `(53845+0)/2`

Which is not what i want. I want for every document the `receive` and `transmit` be averaged for each device alone.

How would one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding another key to group. This resulted in being able to split the documents at an interval AND on the different device names!. This is my aggregation:

```
$aggregation = [
                [
                    '$match' => [
                        'timestamp' => ['$gte' => $todayMidnight],
                        'hostname' => $serverName
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$unwind' => '$networkList'
                ],
                [
                    '$group' => [
                        '_id' => [
                            'interval' => [
                                '$subtract' => [
                                    '$timestamp',
                                    [
                                        '$mod' => ['$timestamp', 300]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                            'name' => '$networkList.name'
                        ],
                        'name' => [
                            '$last' => '$networkList.name'
                        ],
                        'receive' => [
                            '$avg' => '$networkList.receive'
                        ],
                        'transmit' => [
                            '$avg' => '$networkList.transmit'
                        ],
                        'timestamp' => [
                            '$max' => '$timestamp'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$project' => [
                        '_id' => 0,
                        'receive' => 1,
                        'transmit' => 1,
                        'name' => 1,
                        'timestamp' => 1
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    '$sort' => [
                        'timestamp' => -1
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```